# Modifier key pressed during another keypress supresses the 'released' event of the original action

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm trying to create a simple arrow-key movement system, with 'Up', 'Down', 'Left', and 'Right' input actions bound to their respective arrow keys.

Currently, I do the following:

```cs
if (@event.IsPressed())
{
    // handle action "Up", etc. being pressed
}
else
{
    // handle action "Up", etc. being released
}
```

This works well, but if right-crtl is accidentally pressed after 'left' is pressed, but before it is released, and it is released after (so inputs are left down, rctrl down, left up, rctrl up), then the 'released' event is never fired for action 'Left', since it is technically now the modifier action 'ctrl + left'

This results in the released event never being handled, and an additional keypress is required to prevent the character from continuing to move left forever.

This happens once every few minutes when quickly moving around, since right shift also has this problem, and they're both nestled right next to the arrow keys on my keyboard.

Is there an input action configuration change I can make, or a code change I can use to make sure the keypress isn't modified during its press, resulting in this unbalanced 'left down'-'ctrl_left up' event pair?

Comment: I gather you are writing code in `_Input`. Is there any reason why you are not doing this with the `Input` class methods?

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to Godot from Unity, so I'm not surprised I'm doing it wrong

I really don't prefer checking inputs per-frame since I'm using an event-driven structure. Unless you're saying using the Input methods inside _Input,
which makes sense. I'll have to do some testing to figure out what method on Input will help me avoid this issue though.

Comment: In the snippet you posted you are using `IsPressed`, are you using `IsAction`/`IsActionPressed`? Notice there are optional parameters, in particular `exact_match` (I'm not sure how it is capitalized for C#) which should let you decide if modifiers are considered.